# How can Sails.js hook routes be wired to policies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

When defining routes in a Sails.js hook in `routes.after`, it appears that these routes are added after the policies are bound to routes.

Does anyone know how such routes can be made to honour the polices?

The use-case is a hook that represents a pluggable behaviour such as a "blog" hook that adds it's own routes and models to the main application.

Answer (score 0):

To configure policies inside your hook, you can use sails.config.policies.

```
module.exports = function(sails){
    return {
        configure: function(){
            sails.config.policies = {
                '*': false
            };
        },
    };
};
```

Although, if you want to do something async, you would need to use loadModules or initialize instead of configure, but it doesn't work properly.